# Chrome's Speech Recognition API compatible with Google Docs Plug-in?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to use Chrome's speech to text API in a Google Docs plugin that I am creating. I am having trouble integrating the speech to text API in my gs code.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Chrome's speech to text functionality within Google Docs' framework?

Below I have a call in javascript that checks to see if the browser supports the voice to text functionality:

```
    if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) (
       //Perform speech to text translation
    )
```

However, the if statement always evaluates to false, and I am not sure why.

Does anyone have some insight as to why this occurs?